# Primefaces columnToggler remove item from checkbox list

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using a Primefaces columnToggler to dynamically hide/display columns in a data table. This is working as expected, however I would like to remove items from the togglers checklist, so the user cannot check/uncheck them.

*relevant code:*

**button and columnToggler**

```
<p:commandButton id="toggler" 
                 type="button" 
                 value="Columns" 
                 title="Show/Hide columns"/>
<p:columnToggler datasource="my_datatable" 
                 trigger="toggler" />
```

**dataTable**

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{bean.foobars}" var="fb" 
              id="my_datatable"> ...
```

**column to show (working as expected)**

```
 <p:column headerText="Data One" >
      <h:outputText value="#{fb.data1}"/>
 </p:column>
```

**column to hide from columnToggler checklist (how do I do this?)**

```
 <p:column headerText="Always Available" >
      <h:outputText value="#{fb.mustSeeField}"/>
 </p:column>
```

I was hoping to find an attribute on `p:columnToggler` for 'locked' or 'always on' fields, or possibly an attribute on `p:column` to remove it from the columnToggler checklist. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's possible. Thoughts? Solutions? thank you!

Comment: This is effectively a 'RTFM'... The PrimeFaces 6.1 documentation (did not check earlier versions but since you do not post version info, I assume you are using the latest Community Edition). You even ask in the right direction: _"or possibly an attribute on p:column to remove it from the columnToggler checklist"_  This should have shown up using ctrl+space for codecompletion in a decent IDE. So next time please, please, please read documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeFaces has a `toggleable` attribute on the `p:column` as can be seen in the PrimeFaces 6.1 documentation on page 110. So

```
<p:column headerText="Always Available" toggleable="false">
   <h:outputText value="#{fb.mustSeeField}"/>
</p:column>
```

Should do the trick